# I am trying to make a triangle out of a sloop can in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a triangle out of a sloop can a made in the graphics panel but I cant seem to get the code to work right. this is what I have so far.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
public class PyramidSoupCans {
  /**
    * @param args
    */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(800, 800);
    panel.setBackground(new Color(219, 204, 186));
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
      for(int j=1;j<=10-i; j++){
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
      for (int k=1;k<=2 * i-1;k++){
        draw_can( g, i, k);
      }
      System.out.println();
    }}

  public static void draw_can(Graphics g, int x, int y){
    int sizeX = 225;
    int sizeY = 340;
    int cornerX = 37;
    int cornerY = 80;
    g.setColor(new Color(138, 138, 138));
    g.fillRoundRect(cornerX, 246, sizeX, 180, 150, 45);
    g.setColor(new Color(243, 243, 243));
    g.fillRoundRect(cornerX, cornerY, sizeX, sizeY, 150, 45);
    g.setColor(new Color(162,22,5));
    g.fillRoundRect(cornerX, 70, sizeX, 190, 150, 45);
    g.setColor(new Color(138, 138, 138));
    g.fillOval(cornerX, 65, sizeX, 45);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD+Font.ITALIC,45));
    g.drawString("Campbell's",45,150);
    g.setFont(new Font("SanSerif",Font.BOLD,20));
    g.drawString("CONDENSED",85,200);
    g.setColor(new Color(162,22,5));
    g.setFont(new Font("SanSerif",Font.BOLD,40));
    g.drawString("TOMATO",60,360);
    g.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,40));
    g.setColor(new Color(157, 131, 82));
    g.fillOval(113, 223, 70, 70);
    g.drawString("SOUP",95,410);
  }}
```

I am trying to make a triangle out of a sloop can a made in the graphics panel but I cant seem to get the code to work right. this is what I have so far.
That's all. Thanks

Comment: @RzRasel So... the edit you just made was not helpful. Please tell us *what your problem is*. You've only told us about what you want to do, but you've not told us what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to make a triangle, but I did get the soup can to draw.

[image: Pyramid Soup Can]

I made lots of changes to your code.  I did keep your class name, PyramidSoupCans.

The important changes include.

1. I decided to use Swing components, since you named a DrawingPanel that you didn't include as part of your code.
2. You **always** start a Swing application with a call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  This ensures that the Swing components are created and updated on the [Event Dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
3. I created a drawing panel from a JPanel, and put the JPanel in a JFrame with some basic decorations.
4. I put your drawing code in the place where Swing provides a Graphics object to draw on.  You should always override the JPanel paintComponent method when you want to draw on a Swing GUI.

Here's the code:

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PyramidSoupCans implements Runnable {

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new PyramidSoupCans());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Pyramid Soup Cans");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(300, 500);
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4147433638611078320L;

        public DrawingPanel(int width, int height) {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
            this.setBackground(new Color(219, 204, 186));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            int sizeX = 225;
            int sizeY = 340;
            int cornerX = 37;
            int cornerY = 80;

            g.setColor(new Color(138, 138, 138));
            g.fillRoundRect(cornerX, 246, sizeX, 180, 150, 45);
            g.setColor(new Color(243, 243, 243));
            g.fillRoundRect(cornerX, cornerY, sizeX, sizeY, 150, 45);
            g.setColor(new Color(162, 22, 5));
            g.fillRoundRect(cornerX, 70, sizeX, 190, 150, 45);
            g.setColor(new Color(138, 138, 138));
            g.fillOval(cornerX, 65, sizeX, 45);
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 45));
            g.drawString("Campbell's", 45, 150);
            g.setFont(new Font("SanSerif", Font.BOLD, 20));
            g.drawString("CONDENSED", 85, 200);
            g.setColor(new Color(162, 22, 5));
            g.setFont(new Font("SanSerif", Font.BOLD, 40));
            g.drawString("TOMATO", 60, 360);
            g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 40));
            g.setColor(new Color(157, 131, 82));
            g.fillOval(113, 223, 70, 70);
            g.drawString("SOUP", 95, 410);
        }
    }
}
```